# php replace string type parameter=value

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a string that comes from a db: `$text=`

```
parameter1=value1
parameter2=value2
otherparemeter=othervalue
```

I need a function to replace an parameter with a new value, but if parameter does not exist; must to add to string;

Example:   `updatestring ($text,"parameter1","newvalue"):`

Result:

```
parameter1=newvalue
parameter2=value2
otherparemeter=othervalue
```

Or:   `updatestring ($text,"myparameter","myvalue"):`

Result:

```
parameter1=value1
parameter2=value2
otherparemeter=othervalue
myparameter=myvalue
```

thanks !

Comment: [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace)

Comment: does not work with str_replace because i need only replace value part or to add a new line; i think i need regex

Comment: `if (strpos($text, $yourParam) !== false) { // str_replace()... } else { $text .= PHP_EOL . $yourParam . '=' . $yourValue; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @Orangepill; I've corrected your function; now it's working

```
function replacevalue($text, $k, $v){

    $dat = parse_ini_string($text);
    $ret = "";
    if(isset($dat[$k])){
        $dat[$k] = $v;
    } else {
          $dat[$k] = $v;
      }
     foreach($dat as $prop=>$val){
         $ret.= $prop."=".$val."\n";
     }
     return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this might work if every paramater and value are on its own line

```
function updatestring($text, $param1, $param2)
{
    if( stristr($text, $param1.'=') ) $text = preg_replace("`$param1=.*\n`iU", "$param1=$param2".PHP_EOL, $text);
    else $text .= PHP_EOL.$param1.'='.$param2;
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: hello it's adding a value string; and it's replacing; thanks for your help !  result:  parameter1=value1newvalue

Answer (score 1):

Given the format of your input [parse_ini_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php) should work to parse out the data into a structure that can easily be altered and reformated.

Maybe something like this:

```
$a =<<<EOF
parameter1=value1
parameter2=value2
otherparemeter=othervalue
EOF;

function replacevalue($text, $k, $v){
    $dat = parse_ini_string($text);
    $ret = "";
    if(isset($dat[$k])){
        $dat[$k] = $v;
        foreach($dat as $prop=>$val){
            $ret.= $prop."=".$val."\n";
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}
echo replacevalue($a, "parameter1", "Hello World");
```